On what grounds could Elizabeth Anscombe condemn the honoring of Truman, while she personally respected Wittgenstein?
Anscombe famously condemned Oxford's giving former President Truman an honorary degree in her pamphlet "Mr. Truman's Degree," on the ground that he violated an absolute moral rule against intentionally killing civilians in the atomic bombings of Japan. She conceded that the bombings may have saved lives, but called it an instance of a deplorable tendency to allow exceptions from what were once considered absolute, inviolate rules (a theme she developed further in some later essays, including "Modern Moral Philosophy.") She was a stern deontologist throughout her life, insisting that certain rules must never be violated, and that it was wrong to honor people who violated certain rules.
Another such rule, apparently, was one against sodomy/homosexuality, which she mentions in the penultimate paragraph of the Truman pamphlet. She again condemned this along with contraception and abortion in her later essay "On Chastity and Contraception."
Yet Anscombe was a student, colleague, devotee, and family friend of Ludwig Wittgenstein, translating and editing much of his work. Wittgenstein's sexuality was not publicly known until Bartley's 1973 biography, and Anscombe both wrote a letter to the Times casting questioning Bartley's evidence, and wrote in a private letter that if she could "press a button" which would prevent anyone from ever inquiring into Wittgenstein's private life, she would do so. But it is difficult to believe that she was wholly ignorant that Wittgenstein had several homosexual lovers, one of whom continued to be a friend of Anscombe's after Wittgenstein's death; she was morally rigid, but hardly imperceptive.
To be sure, giving someone an honorary degree is not the same as being someone's friend and colleague. Nor need we suppose that she thought that committing sodomy was just as wrong as killing civilians in war. Nevertheless, it seems to me that in some sense she did "honor" Wittgenstein in a way appropriate to her capacities, just as Oxford honored Mr. Truman in a different way. And each were so honored, surely not because they violated certain of Ms. Anscombe's rules, but in spite of their doing so, in virtue of their other praiseworthy accomplishments. I am not aware that Anscombe has expressed any principled distinction between the wrongness of, and the appropriate response to, the violation of these two rules, but think that some such explanation is required when she went out of her way to compare the two.
I do not think that this can be defended merely because, e.g., Wittgenstein's sexuality was not widely known, and homosexuality was at that time not the topic of polite conversation, while Truman's war orders were. For Anscombe was clearly in favor of not making the former known, while while her pamphlet rejects certain attempts to obscure the causal relationship between Truman and the bombings. And there's little point to condemning sodomy in the abstract if, in practice, it is not seen or talked about, and the moralists actually sweep under the rug any attempt to talk about it.
Nor can we easily explain the distinction on the ground that bombing is more harmful than sodomy; many people think that the latter is actually worse in a way because it harms "one's soul." I don't know if Anscombe thought that, but in any case she rejected the view that morality was based on actual or expected consequences. She thought that intended consequences were relevant, and devoted much attention to the distinction between intending and merely foreseeing a result. E.g., Truman intended the bombing of a city, while rejecting the bombing would have only foreseen without intending the harm of the continued war. But of course homosexuals do not intend any harm at all by their actions, so this can't explain why she would think these two rules were both wrong to violate.
I am certainly not looking for reasons why Anscombe should have honored Wittgenstein, or tolerated his sexuality: I think she ought have done both. I am, rather, asking if Anscombe was inconsistent in condemning Truman and those who honored him, while also condemning homosexuality but honoring in her personal life a homosexual philosopher. Or is there some distinction in her works, or in deontological morality generally, which could account for or justify making a greater distinction than I am seeing between her behavior and those who granted Truman an honorary degree?
I fear that my earlier version of this question sounded more biographical and personal, and have re-written it to focus more squarely on the philosophical issue (my apologies to those commenting on earlier versions of the question; I felt it was important to re-write it to satisfy the moderators). The question is whether Anscombe's views on moral philosophy and intention provide us with resources to make the distinction she appears to have made in practice. I would most appreciate responses from people who have read Anscombe's works in detail--I have, but perhaps I am benighted in failing to see therein any basis for her different responses to these violations of supposed moral rules.

I'd say that Anscombe was perhaps bigotted and intellectually dishonest in making that button press remark (and also incoherent in her moral philosophy in general). But if she honestly didn't believe that W. had homosexual contacts, I don't see how you can make her out as hypocritical. If she did believe this, then of course it's hypocritical. Also, if she merely believed that there might be evidence, but she wanted to prevent this from being known - I would see this as hypocritical and not as actually "honoring" Wittgenstein.

There is no reason to assume that every opinion of a philosopher is "noble" and worth to be discussed. See Heidegger.

@ScottForschler - In that case, yes, I think she was being hypocritical. I haven't read those later biographies, so still wouldn't be able to tell, of course.  I think Mauro's point is that there is no reason to suppose that Anscombe only had "noble" opinions. So, the implicit question is really - why is this a big deal to you? And what does your question have to do with philosophy?... :)

Ok - So, I think in that case, your question might benefit from more philosophical context (otherwise it's in acute danger of quickly being closed by others on this forum, I notice that its already being downvoted). You seem to be linking orthodox catholicism + absolute moral principles + something like taking a personal stance, linking all that to hypocrisy. But what's the question? Should A. have been more self-critical? More open-minded? And what's the general question? Is it about A's moral position?

(I have to say I was pretty shocked to learn that Dummett as adolescent had converted to Roman Catholicism -- this I can easily forgive -- and stayed a practising member all his life -- which to me seems inconceivable of any decent human being.)

Truman was publicly honored for his official act as president, Anscombe 'honored' Wittgenstein as a philosopher, which his private life had little to do with. I am not sure how being friendly amounts to 'honoring', hate the sin and not the sinner as they say. There might have been some hypocrisy involved on Anscombe's part concerning sodomy, but it hardly comes out when her friendship is contrasted to Truman's degree.

Hi everybody! Please bear in mind that comments are not intended for long discussions. We have chatrooms for that.

Tsundoku makes a good point, and since I realized that most of my replies were simply reminding people of things I already said in my longish question, I deleted them (adding, temporarily, this new one). I would encourage others to delete theirs as well if they are no longer pertinent. As earlier noted, I clarified the question somewhat in an added, final paragraph in response to earlier comments.

I'm a little disappointed that this question was deemed unphilosophical. Earlier this summer I attended a conference on Anscombe's philosophy, where over half the papers were devoted to her conception of morality as consisting of absolute rules, and one paper argued that her work on intention and agency as well as morality flowed from an attempt to further flesh out her condemnation of those who violated certain rules which she considered absolutely inviolable, as laid out in her pamphlet on "Mr. Truman's Degree." Perhaps I didn't explain the philosophy here as well as others did there.

I wonder if the powers that be could explain their decision on this a little more, as I truly remain a bit puzzled about why this question was rejected. Did perhaps the word "hypocrisy" suggest that I was asking a primarily biographical question? If I had asked instead whether her ethical views were "inconsistent" would that have made it more clear that I was not asking, e.g., if she was a nice person (or something like that), but rather about her philosophical views? (Which, of course, shaped her personal decisions, but I'm asking primarily about the views behind these.)

Without clarity on this, I don't know if I can ask, e.g., questions about what philosophers do and how their work influences their lives, or if we must only ask about what they have written, setting aside any questions about whether their lives shed any light about their philosophical views, spoken or unspoken?

It seems to me now that the problem might be not that the question was "not philosophical," as the closure comments suggest--for it certainly is--but that it was too open-ended, and hence not conducive to a sufficiently precise answer. This is fair, I just wish that the explanation for closing the question had itself been more precise if this was indeed the problem.

There's a lot of detail floating about here, but we should focus on the actual issue that you asked about.

I am asking if Anscombe was a hypocrite for condemning Truman and those who honored him, while also condemning homosexuality but honoring in her personal life a homosexual philosopher.

We need to know whether she knew he was homosexual.
You say:-

But she can't possibly have been ignorant that Wittgenstein had several homosexual lovers, one of whom continued to be a friend of Anscombe's after Wittgenstein's death.

I don't know what evidence you have, but you clearly don't have direct evidence that she did know. If you had such evidence, you would have said so.
It seems very unlikely that she would have even thought about actively probing his sex life, any more that she would have probed anyone else's. Wittgenstein, knowing her faith, would have been as discreet as possible. So it is perfectly possible that she never did have conclusive evidence.
Let's supposing that she did know or suspect.
For a Roman Catholic, the appropriate action for a sinner is confession, repentance and reform. I understand that confessors are expected to urge sinners who have broken the law to confess publicly and accept the punishment as essential steps for repentance. But they are expected not to inform on their penitents.
It seems to me that, if Anscombe was confronted with irrefutable evidence, she would have needed to confront Wittgenstein and urge him to confess, but would not have needed to take any further action. That would not have been hypocritical.
She might well have considered whether there was some significant difference between the two cases that would justify treating them differently. Truman took action as President of the USA that was designed to shorten the war and, he believed, saved many American lives. He took that action knowing that it would cost the lives of very many Japanese people. Wittgenstein had no significant public life and harmed no-one. You may think that the difference is not significant. But it would not be hypocritical to believe that it is.
You quote her remark in the Truman pamphlet that the rule against sodomy "admits of no exception". Nothing follows about what is an appropriate response to the two cases.
You also say:-

... there's little point to condemning sodomy in the abstract if, in practice, it is not seen or talked about, and the moralists actually sweep under the rug any attempt to talk about it.

I think you are referring to Anscombe's defence of Wittgenstein's privacy in the light of Barrett's book. If she didn't know (and didn't accept the evidence in the book) her defence was not hypocritical. But there's another issue here, whether it was reasonable or necessary to publish the fact (or evidence, if there's any doubt).
I must admit to a bias here, that I am not at all interested in Wittgenstein's sex life, so I do not see any necessity to publish either fact or evidence. But I accept that others might disagree and respect that.
There might possibly be a justification if the issue casts light on his life. Does it? I don't know.
But I also have to accept that the private life of the dead is not as sacrosanct as the private life of the living. So I agree with you that the "press a button" remark, though understandable, is over the top.
There is a more general question involved here, about the appropriate action when we are confronted with the sins of the past. It is very frustrating that the only substantial action, so far as I can see, is to ensure that the record is set straight.
We will express our outrage in various ways. Apologies and restitutions or compensations might sometimes be possible and appropriate. All that is very well, but changes nothing. In the end, nothing can change the past.

the private life of the dead is not as sacrosanct as the private life of the living -1 for that.  AFAIC: The dead are not gone if we refer their works but they cant defend themselves. Apples to both LW and GEMA. I am not at all interested in Wittgenstein's sex life +2 for that. Total +1

I'm not terribly interested in Wittgenstein's sex life either. My point is that Anscombe seemed to be so interested in that she often wanted to condemn them. And she was also interested in condemning certain difficult wartime decisions, and those who honored anyone she wanted to condemn. And it seems to me that she was inconsistent about this. "Wittgenstein...harmed no-one." Of course; but Anscombe's absolute moral rules had little to do with harm (even the bombing, she admits, reduced the total harm caused). I think that's nuts, but that's kind of my point.

@rushi I was reporting a fact about the dead, not endorsing it. ("I have to accept...") There is, indeed, an unfairness about the practice. Who/what are LW and GEMA?  But thanks for the pluses.

Ludwig Wittgenstein G.E.M. Anscombe

@Rushi Of course.

I don't think that condemning both means that she thought they were equally harmful or that the same action was required in response to them. The paragraph about Roman Catholicism was meant to address that.

Ludwig V: perhaps you're right that she didn't think similar/analogous actions were required in response. But I'm trying to figure out how she could have made a principled decision between these responses. I think we at least need an explanation of this, and I'm not sure she ever provided one, or the basis of one. That's what I'm asking: if someone can see in her philosophical works some principle(s) underlying this distinction.

Ludwig V: for one could think otherwise. Years ago I heard that a philosopher was hired at Notre Dame on her philosophical merit. At a welcome party, another philosopher (perhaps Plantinga) was about to shake her hand when she introduced her wife; he instantly withdrew his hand, walked away, and never spoke to her again at meetings etc. I find this response reprehensible; but I understand it: he didn't want to honor a relationship he condemned. I'm asking how Anscombe could defend a different response when she thought it so obvious that we must refuse to honor someone else who broke her rules.

Anscombe was not a priest bound by confessional privacy, and she could have done more to fail to honor Wittgenstein: persistently withdraw from his presence, as illustrated in the above story. While it is remotely possible that she never got any hints of Wittgenstein's sexuality during his lifetime, I find it difficult to ascribe such obtuseness to her; she was stern in her morality, but hardly imperceptive about the world. I do not know if LW's sexuality casts any light on his philosophy; I am suggesting that it casts some light on GEMA's.

There's an awful lot here. It could be a really interesting, even fruitful, discussion. But I hate discussing through the keyhole of comments. Would you be interested in joining a chat room? [https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/154935/discussion-about-anscombe-truman-wittgenstein-ethics]
